# Displaying Google Map in android application by using the values stored in MySQL database

Tags: android, mysql, google-maps

I have a android code which will find the latitude and longitude values using NETWORK PROVIDER and stores it(lat and lon values) in SERVER using static IP, as well as in MYSQL DATABASE. This works fine..

I now need to write a client application which retrieves the latitude and longitude value from MYSQL database and displays it in google map in android. How to do it. I am struck up with this for past 4 days. Please help me to find a solution

The following is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Location location;
protected LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener ll ;
private TextView tv ;
EditText msgTextField;
int delay = 1000;
int period=10000;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    boolean gpsEnabled = true;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   // AlarmManager manager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
    tv= new TextView (this);
    try {
    gpsEnabled =locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
  //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ggg ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    locationManager. requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 20000, 5, new MyLocationListener()); 
    Log.d("gps","Gps supports altitude"+ locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).supportsAltitude());
    List<String> providers=locationManager.getAllProviders();
    for(String provider : providers)
    {
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,provider,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    for(int w=0;w <providers.size();w++)
    {
    Log.d("Location Test ","provider "+w +":"+providers.get(w));

    }
    providers =locationManager.getProviders(true);

    final Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            showCurrentLocation();


        }
    });

   Button send1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sendButton1);

    send1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent viewIntent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,Mapview.class);
            startActivity(viewIntent);

        }
    });


  Button start=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.startSercice1);


start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SimpleService.class));    

    }
});
  Button stop=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.stopService1);
  stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SimpleService.class));

}
 });
 } 

protected void showCurrentLocation() 
    { 

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (location != null) 
    {

   // double dd = location.getAltitude();
    String message = String.format( "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s  ",location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude() );
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xx.xx.xx.xx/YourPhpScript1.php");
    try {
       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message));
       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
       httpclient.execute(httppost);

     }
 catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {

    } 
 catch (IOException e)
   {

   }


    }

    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener 
    {

    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location)
    { 

        final String message = String.format( "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s  ",location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xx.xx.xx.xx/YourPhpScript1.php");
        double LONGITUDE = location.getLongitude();
        double LATITUDE = location.getLatitude();
        TextView myAddress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myaddress);

        try
        {
          Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
          List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);

          if(addresses != null) {
           Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
           StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
           for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
            strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
            String add = strReturnedAddress.toString();
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", add));
           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           httpclient.execute(httppost);
           }
          myAddress.setText(strReturnedAddress.toString());
          }

          else
          {
           myAddress.setText("No Address returned!");
          }



        }
     catch (IOException e) 
     {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
          myAddress.setText("Canont get Address!");
     }

  //  double ddd =location.getAltitude();


//   pendingIntent =PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this,1,intent,1);
        final String message1 = String.format( "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s  ",location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask()
    {

    public void run()
    { 

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xx.xx.xx.xx/YourPhpScript1.php");
 try { 

       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message));
       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

  //manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+200000, pendingIntent);
       httpclient.execute(httppost);

     }

 catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {

    } 
 catch (IOException e)
   {

   }

  }
  },60000);



  }

    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) 
    { 
    Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "Provider status changed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    } 
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s)
    { 
    Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this,"Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String s)
    { 
    Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this,"Provider enabled by the user",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    }




}
```

Comment: Can you please show some code? I can't help you if you don't

Comment: @redelman431 see my question. I have edited it

Answer (score 0):

you have to get the latitude and longitude from your database using AsyncTask, after that, you can use webView to show the map and the marker.

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/android_v3

Comment: I have problem in retrieving value from database from inside android application.. How to do that